# Curious behaviour with static_assert and CRTP

Tags: c++, c++17, crtp, static-assert

While developing a protocol library, I used some preventive `static_assert` to check whether some different arrays had the same length.

At first, I started using them in all derived classes, but at some moment, I wondered why not to put that protection in base class (the CRTP base class) and save in typewording. I did it, but I then found that it was not possible to do as I expected and I would like to know: 1st/ why? and 2nd/ is it fixable in some way?

The minimal working example of original source code can be this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<typename T>
struct skill
{
    static constexpr void some_function() { static_assert(T::vars.size() == T::bits.size()); }//This is OK
    static_assert(T::vars.size() == T::bits.size());//This one arises an error!!!
    
private:
    skill() = default;
    friend T;
};


struct message1 : skill<message1>
{
    static constexpr std::array vars{ "id", "len", "source", "destination" };
    static constexpr std::array bits{ 8, 10, 12, 12 };
    static_assert(vars.size() == bits.size());//This is OK
};


struct message2 : skill<message2>
{
    static constexpr std::array vars{ "id", "len", "command" };
    static constexpr std::array bits{ 8, 10, 24 };
    static_assert(vars.size() == bits.size());//This is OK
};


int main()
{
    message1::some_function();
}
```

Please, note `static_assert` in `struct skill`, which is the one arisen the next error: "error: incomplete type 'message1' used in nested name specifier" in g++.

The link to source code in coliru is: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24a1916a5055949a

Please, any help with this?

Comment: The body of the function is instantiated only when it's called, and by that time, `T` is a complete type. But the second `static_assert` is evaluated as soon as `skill<message1>` itself is instantiated, and at point, `message1` is still an incomplete type - the definitions of `vars` and `bits` haven't been seen yet. It's basically as if you moved the `static_assert` that's currently right below `bits` two lines up, so it's above `vars` and `bits`; you'd get the same error then.

Comment: An `std::array` of `std::pair` or some `constexpr struct` might be an alternative although both construction and usage will have to change. If your `struct` only accept 2 parameters constructor, then you are sure that for each pair both values are set by design. It can even improve readability if at initialisation, each pair is on its own line.